# how to keep process from swamping server

Tags: command-line, server, process, convert

I have a webserver, where images are being collected and converted to gifs.
Im using the convert program from image-magick, at about every 1000 images. 
The process while it runs completely inundates my server.

I still only want to convert 1000+ images into a gif. How can I keep the system resources required by `convert` from putting too much system load on my server?

Comment: Some added detail might help us to determine the root cause of your issue. Are you experiencing High CPU usage, High Io-waits, excessive swapping due to low RAM? any and all of these can have a noticeable impact on performance. The best solutions vary depending on the root cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a simple answer that will increase the time it takes to convert your images will suffice, the easy answer to to launch `convert` using `nice` for example:

`nice -n 19 convert ...` (Where ... is the rest of your current convert command) will reduce the priority of the convert program from 20 (the default) to 39

The exact effect of setting a particular niceness value for a process depends on the details of how the scheduler is designed on that implementation of Unix/Linux. A particular operating system's scheduler will also have various heuristics built into it (e.g. to favor processes that are mostly I/O-bound over processes that are CPU-bound).

As a simple example, when two otherwise identical CPU-bound processes are running simultaneously on a single-CPU Linux system, each one's share of the CPU time will be proportional to 20 − p, where p is the process' priority. Thus a process run with nice +15 will receive 25% of the CPU time allocated to a normal-priority process: (20 − 15)/(20 − 0) = 0.25.[2] On the BSD 4.x scheduler, on the other hand, the ratio in the same example is about ten to one.

Sources:

`man nice`

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_(Unix)

Answer (score 2):

Imagemagick has built in method for resource usage control. You can limit resources available to imagemagick in policy.xml file. By default on Ubuntu it's probably located at `/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml`

There are multiple options to play with, for example you can set the limit on threads to a number smaller than the count of your CPU cores, enable CPU throttling and/or limit memory usage according to what's available on your server.

You can view current settings with `identify -list resource` command.

Comment: This is excellent to know!

Answer (score 1):

If it is eating I/O and CPU then run it with ionice and nice. Note that ionice only works if you are using the CFQ block I/O scheduler.  This I/O scheduler can be set on a block device (for example, /dev/sda) using:

```
echo "cfq" | sudo tee /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
```

and then run your process using:

```
ionice -c 2 -n 7 nice -n 19 <your command>
```

..this will run the process with the best-effort I/O niceness at the lowest level 7 with the lowest CPU niceness level.